# Angular Unit test of pipe transfome type string[]

Tags: angular, typescript, testing

I trying to make test unit for this pipe with angular/typeScript:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'getCausesFromListCountDailyDelay'
})
export class GetCausesFromListCountDailyDelayPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(listCountDailyDelay: ListCountDelay[]): string[] {
    return listCountDailyDelay.map(count => count.cause.charAt(0) + '     ' + count.totalTime);
  }
}
```

and when I eecute the test I have problem

```
error TS2339: Property 'toEqual' does not exist on type 'string[]
```

my test file :

```
 it('should GetCausesFromListCountDailyDelayPipe', () => {
    const listCountDailyDelay: ListCountDelay[] = [
      {
        centre: 'LFAF',
        cause: 'CCCC',
        totalTime: 5
      },
      {
        centre: 'LFFF',
        cause: 'IIII',
        totalTime: 20
      },
      {
        centre: 'LFF',
        cause: 'FHHH',
        totalTime: 10
      },
    ];
    const resultDatas: ListCountDelay[] = [
      {
        centre: 'LFAF',
        cause: 'C    ',
        totalTime: 5
      },
      {
        centre: 'LFFF',
        cause: 'I    ',
        totalTime: 20
      },
      {
        centre: 'LFF',
        cause: 'F    ',
        totalTime: 10
      },
    ];

    expect(pipe.transform(listCountDailyDelay).toEqual(resultDatas)));
  });
```

the pipe transform return type string[] but I can not do this test with Equal or toBe !!!
any idea please ?!!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a right parenthesis for 'expect' :

```
expect(pipe.transform(listCountDailyDelay)).toEqual(resultDatas));
```

Comment: you are right but the same error persists again

Comment: I when I change ```Equal``` by ```toString``` it looks good, but I am not sur the difference between toEqual and use ToString like : ```expect(pipe.transform(listCountDailyDelay)).toString(resultDatas));
```